# Error with multiple If then, else if

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm new in ASP development.

This is my source code :

```
ident = request.Form("ident")
pass=request.Form("passe")
response.write(ident)
response.write(pass)

if pass= "m" and ident="m" Then 
    Session("connect")="membre"
    response.redirect("../")
else if pass= "g" and ident="g" Then 
        Session("connect")="gest"
        response.redirect("../")
else if pass= "a" and ident="a" Then
        Session("connect")="admin"
        response.redirect("../")
else    
    response.redirect("ident.asp")
End If
```

But, with this code, I get this :

> "Erreur de compilation Microsoft VBScript error '800a0401'
>
> Fin d'instruction attendue
>
> /iisHelp/common/500-100.asp, line 11
>
> Dim objASPError, blnErrorWritten, strServername, strServerIP,
>   strRemoteIP Dim strMethod, lngPos, datNow, strQueryString, strURL
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------^
>
> Erreur de compilation Microsoft VBScript error '800a03f6'
>
> 'End' attendu
>
> /groupe2/stage23/TP3/verif_id.asp, line 18 "

Comment: Is there any way you can move to ASP.NET?

Comment: ElseIf must be one word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like earlier in your file -- line 11 -- you've accidentally deleted a newline that's making DIM statements collide.  This is throwing the whole file out of synch in the parser.

Split that one line DIM statement into two lines (or kill the second DIM -- your choice) and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 9):

`Else If` in VB must be written in one word, without whitespace separator – **`ElseIf`**.

Answer (score 4):

[**VBScript Else if Statemen**](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_conditionals.asp)t

must be `elseif` or `ElseIf` (without space)

```
if pass= "m" and ident="m" Then 
    Session("connect")="membre"
    response.redirect("../")
elseif pass= "g" and ident="g" Then 
        Session("connect")="gest"
        response.redirect("../")
elseif pass= "a" and ident="a" Then
        Session("connect")="admin"
        response.redirect("../")
else    
    response.redirect("ident.asp")
End If
```